# flex linkbutton text to span 2 lines

Tags: apache-flex, multiline, linkbutton

is there a way to span the text of a link button to 2 lines? so instead of "Save Page" to be in one line only, I want it to be in 2 lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To achive this, you will have to create a custom Button-class, which extends the Button-class. There is a nice Blog about this on the Adobe site:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/04/multiline_buttons.html

It focussed on creating a multiline Radiobutton, but you can easily apply it for a button.